# Как использовать пробел в h1 с тэгом br

Tags: html5, seo

У меня такая ситуация:

```
<h1 style="display:inline-block;position:relative;top:-23px;background:#f8f8f8;font-size:36px;max-width:400px;line-height:36px;padding:0 8px;">
    '.$result['breadcrumb'][1]['name'].'
    <br>
    '.$result['name'].'
</h1>
```

Дело в том что там 2 предложения, но при анализе заголовков программой SEO, он мне их выдает как сливающиеся слова после `br`. Полагаю, что это какой то атрибут для `h1` или тэг после `br`, но не могу найти какой. Не `&nsbp` же использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте пробел перед тегом `<br />` (или в конце первой строки). Возможно даже неразрывный пробел

```
&nbsp;
```

Comment: Помог неразрывный пробел,спасибо, но мне кажется что это всегда моветон в коде. Есть ли вариант без него?! Вот в чем вопрос.

Comment: @Лось а в чем заключается моветон? Это специальный HTML спецсимвол, означающий неразрывный пробел